# Perl: parsing compressed files

Tags: perl, compression, gzip

I have a script that opens a big text-file and extracts data to create a report.

**Question:**

Is there a way to open the file in perl even if the file has been compressed with `gzip`?

`Gunzip` the file before opening would be to slow.

**Example:**

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt.gz")
```

Answer (score 2):

[IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.html) module can help you.

```
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError) ;
unzip $input_filename_or_reference => $output_filename_or_reference [,OPTS] 
    or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
```

The functional interface needs Perl5.005 or better.

Or You can use CPAN module [PerlIO::gzip](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/PerlIO-gzip-0.19/gzip.pm):

```
use PerlIO::gzip;
open FOO, "<:gzip", "file.gz" or die $!;
print while <FOO>; # And it will be uncompressed...

binmode FOO, ":gzip(none)" # Starts reading deflate stream from here on
```

`PerlIO::gzip` provides a PerlIO layer that manipulates files in the format used by the `gzip` program. Compression and Decompression are implemented, but not together. If you attempt to open a file for reading and writing the open will fail.